# Spring Managed Schedulers Status

Tags: spring

Is there a way to check the list of schedulers that are currently managed in a spring application context?
i have an application where I have configured a quartz scheduler and I want to check whether that scheduler is active ( I do not mean that the scheduler is currently executing the job).
This is something like checking whether a web resource is active by calling the url of that web resource and checking for a response (200 or 404).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you may do one of the following:

- If you only need to check this during application startup, you can just check the logs. quartz logs when it starts. You need to configure your logger to have the "org.springframework.scheduling.quartz" namespace logged in debug mode
- To check anytime if the scheduler is started, you can use the quartz jmx capabilities. You enable this just by adding "org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export = true" in the quartz properties file. Then you can open a JConsole targeting your application, and when it opens, there will be available a "quartz" node underneath you will find various attributes and operations. The first one is actually the "started" which will be true if the scheduler is started which is what you asked, but there are many others too

If you do not know how to open a JConsole, consult sun's documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html as this is a different topic and too much to describe here

- You may have access to such information programmatically too, by injecting the Scheduler bean where you wish to access it from, and calling the scheduler.isStarted() method. But this way you will have implement a way that exposes this information on demand somehow
- In case you use quartz database, you also have the option to check inside QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE table that the checkin times change every few seconds if the scheduler is running